# In deep learning, what is the difference between "disentangled representation" and "distributed representation"

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-engineering

People talk about how neural network should learn "disentangled representation" rather than "distributed representation" so that a deep learning model is more interpretable and understandable. What are the definition of these two terms and any particular example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's say the following vectors are respectively representations for 
a ball: [1,0,0,0]
and 
a car: [0,1,0,0]

In this representation a single neuron learns the meaning of a ball or a car without having to rely on other neurons. This is a disentangled representation, which is meant to facilitate the understanding of artificial neural networks.

This in contrast to distributed representations, for example, a ball: [0.1,-0.02,0.45,0.06] and a car: [-0.78,-0.1,0.83,0.01]. In this case, an object is represented by a particular location in the vector space. This type of representation is for example the outcome of the word2vec algorithms.